# Jira worklog per project using JQL

Tags: jquery, jira, jira-agile

how to find ***"total hours spent"*** for a specific project using JQL search?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do aggregate queries using JQL.

You may want to look at the plugins below if you need to report from Jira.  If this is just a one off, then you could simply export the results into excel and aggregate from there.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jira-timesheet-plugin/server/overview

https://eazybi.com/products/eazybi_jira

Answer (score 0):

If this is a rare/infrequent request and there are not many issues in the project (less than 1000 issues with hours logged), you can simply use JIRA native JQL and spreadsheet to get the total hours spent.

- First enter a jql query such as this: `project = xyz and timespent is not empty`
- Then add the "Time Spent" column to the jql page.
- Export to csv/Excel and open the file in Excel/Google spreadsheet.
- You can then sum up the "Time Spent" column using the sum formula
  e.g. =sum(B2:B500). Remember to divide by 3600 to get the hours spent
  as the time unit is tracked in second.

We get this kind of requests occasionally (~once a month) and this is relatively easy to do without the need for any extra add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, now it is possible using aggregate expression.

Using JQL:

`project = xxx and issueFunction in aggregateExpression("Total time spent", "timespent.sum()")`

Yields the following message right above search results:

`Total time spent:  123 h 45 min`

However availability of this funtion could be limited based on which Jira version/edition you are using.